# Wronskian of the ODE $u''(t)+P(t)u'(t)+Q(t)u(t)=R(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given equation $$u''(t)+P(t)u'(t)+Q(t)u(t)=R(t)$$ where $P,Q$ and $R$ are continuous functions defined on $t\in[0,1]$ and $u_1$ and $u_2$ be two solutions of this ODE. Then which of the following  is the Wronskian $W$.

1. $W(t)=2t-1,~0\leq t \leq 1$
2. $W(t)=\sin{2\pi t},~0\leq t \leq 1$
3. $W(t)=\cos{2\pi t},~0\leq t \leq 1$
4. $W(t)=1,~0\leq t \leq 1$

This is a non-homogeneous case. I do know how to find the Wronskian for the homogeneous case by using the relation $W'=uv''-vu''$ but I failed with the non-homogeneous case with this trick. How can I do this?

Also if it says $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two solutions then does it implies they are necessarily linearly independent, in general? How can I conclude this?

Comment: Anybody with hints??

Comment: First you should answer one simple question: **WHY** you want to define Wronskian for two solutions of **non**homogeneous equation?

Comment: @Evgeny because the question asked me to do so.

Comment: The question is how you DEFINE it. What properties do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wronskian is **always** associated with a homogeneous equation, hence the question is about the Wronskian of the corresponding homogeneous equation, not the Wronskian of the equation itself.

By [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity), the Wronskian is either zero for all $t\in [0,1]$, or else it is never zero. Now let's look at the options:

1. $2t-1$ is equal to zero at $t=1/2$, but not equal to zero at some other points in $[0,1]$, so it is not the Wronskian.
2. $\sin 2\pi t$ is equal to zero at $t=1/2$, but not equal to zero at some other points in $[0,1]$, so it is not the Wronskian.
3. $\cos 2\pi t$ is equal to zero at $t=1/4$, but not equal to zero at some other points in $[0,1]$, so it is not the Wronskian.

It follows that among the four options given, only $W(t)=1\,\forall t\in[0,1]$ can be the Wronskian, that is, if it is known that it must be one of these four.

Comment: I find your usage of the word "identically" strange. These functions aren't "non-zero identically" precisely because they do have zeros at points in the required interval.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: You didn't say the functions "are not identically zero" (that would be correct). You said they are "non-zero identically." This is false, because they do vanish somewhere.